# compare two dates in angular js expressions and do a ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to compare two Date string in Angular JS Expressions

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="app">

    <div>{{Today}}</div>
    <div>{{ItemDate}}</div>
    <div>{{ItemDate<Today}}</div>
  </body>
```

Script

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('app', controller);

function controller($scope){
  $scope.ItemDate="2018-07-16T14:23:57.566Z";
  $scope.Today= new Date();
}
```

I am trying to do a ng-hide if `{{ItemDate<Today}}`

[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JZ4wTsZ0qfIiefbCYIB4?p=preview)

Do Angular Expressions have this capability? I want to do this without changing the script part.

Comment: The use of interpolation with {{ }} can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. It makes it more difficult to understand, debug, test, and maintain. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have such logic in your template is not a good idea. You can compare dates in your JS code [plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/V50eN660CCpxhfyCMyOL?p=preview)

```
 $scope.ItemDate="2018-07-16T14:23:57.566Z";
 $scope.Today= new Date();
 $scope.hideDate = (new Date($scope.ItemDate) - $scope.Today < 0);
```

Comment: upvoted thanks, any specific reason on why its not a good idea?
I might have to do a `for each` in the ajax returned array to do this, so I thought I will just do it using expressions

Comment: @VigneshSubramanian It's just considered a good practice. Angular (unlike react) allows you only to use some simple values in your template, and all logic is performed by angular directives (ng-if etc.). You don't have access to javascript, so, for example, you can't convert your dates in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your expression in ng-hide:

```
<div ng-hide="{{(ItemDate|date)<(Today|date)}}">{{ItemDate}}</div>
```

This will hide the div with the expression.

As Martin said, beware of using these logic in your template.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the above error, 
it does not really work with the dates tested. 
Here is an example to work, following Martin's line of thought and adding ng-hide in html:

html:

```
<div>{{Today}}</div>    
<div>{{ItemDate}}</div> 
<div ng-hide="CompareDate">{{ItemDate}}</div>
```

script:

```
$scope.ItemDate="2018-07-16T16:23:57.566Z";
$scope.Today= new Date();
$scope.CompareDate = (new Date($scope.ItemDate) < $scope.Today);
```

Comment: The interpolation with `{{ }}` can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. It can make it more difficult to debug, test, and maintain.

Comment: Doesn't work with 2019-07-16 < today. The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEBfC8grUh0hYLz11EMZ?p=preview)